# How do I remove all annotations from MKMapView except the user location annotation? 

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation, userlocation

I use `removeAnnotations` to remove my annotations from `mapView` but same it remove user location ann. How can I prevent this, or how to get user ann back to view?

```
NSArray *annotationsOnMap = mapView.annotations;
        [mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsOnMap];
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Update:

When I tried with the iOS 9 SDK the user annotation is no longer removed. You can simply use

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
```

---

Historical answer (for apps that run on iOS before iOS 9):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray * annotationsToRemove = [ mapView.annotations mutableCopy ] ;
[ annotationsToRemove removeObject:mapView.userLocation ] ;
[ mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove ] ;
```

EDIT: Swift version

```
let annotationsToRemove = mapView.annotations.filter { $0 !== mapView.userLocation }
mapView.removeAnnotations( annotationsToRemove )
```

Comment: I've tried using this instead: self.mapView.viewForAnnotation(annotation!)?.hidden = true but it was giving me weird errors when I change map region. Yours is the better way, thank you!

Comment: I implemented this code but I get a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil. I checked whether annotationsToRemove counts greater than one. I have no idea why I am getting this error. Please help me.

Comment: you have to look and see what line is failed on

Comment: It's in the MapView.removeAnnotations line

Comment: Do you have any `!` in your code? How is your MapView variable defined? Change any `!` to `?` and then further modify your code so it compiles. The crash will probably be resolved.

Answer (score 21):

To clear all the annotations from the map:

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];
```

To remove specified annotations from Mapview

```
 for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations)
{
    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
              [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];   
    }

}
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: This answer is much more concise than the accepted one.

Answer (score 7):

For Swift you can simply use a one-liner:

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
```

Edit: As nielsbot mentioned it will also remove the user's location annotation unless you have set it up like this:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

Comment: this removes all the annotations, which is not what OP wanted.

Comment: The behavior has changed.

Answer (score 3):

If your user location is kind of class of `MKUserLocation`, use `isKindOfClass` to avoid removing user location annotation.

```
if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {

}
```

Else you can set a flag to recognize the kind of your annotations in `– mapView:viewForAnnotation:`.

Answer (score 1):

> Swift 4.2 or later

**Add this line before adding the annotations**

```
mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations.filter { $0 !== mapView.userLocation })
```

Comment: Most efficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about some `NSPredicate` filter?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"className != %@", NSStringFromClass(MKUserLocation.class)];
NSArray *nonUserAnnotations = [self.mapView.annotations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:nonUserAnnotations];
```

*Life is always better with NSPredicate filter*

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 4.1**:

Normally if you don't want to remove your ***MKUserLocation*** annotation you can simply run:

`self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.annotations)`.

This method by default does not remove the ***MKUserLocation*** annotation from the `annotations` list.

However if you need to filter out all annotations except the ***MKUserLocation*** (see `annotationsNoUserLocation` variable below) for any other reason, like centering on all the annotations but the ***MKUserLocation*** annotation you can use this simple extension below.

```
extension MKMapView {

    var annotationsNoUserLocation : [MKAnnotation] {
        get {
            return self.annotations.filter{ !($0 is MKUserLocation) }
        }
    }

    func showAllAnnotations() {
        self.showAnnotations(self.annotations, animated: true)
    }

    func removeAllAnnotations() {
        self.removeAnnotations(self.annotations)
    }

    func showAllAnnotationsNoUserLocation() {
        self.showAnnotations(self.annotationsNoUserLocation, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi try this i got the solution from this code:

```
 NSMutableArray*listRemoveAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[Mapview removeAnnotations:listRemoveAnnotations];

 [listRemoveAnnotations release];
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. In fact this code as no effect--`listRemoveAnnotations` is empty when `-removeAnimations` is called.