# Remove user location annotation from mapView

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mkuserlocation

I have to remove all the annotations added to my MKMapView but when I execute :

```
NSMutableArray *annotationsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: mapView.annotations];
[mapView removeAnnotations: annotationsToRemove];
```

The array annotationsToRemove contains a `MKUserLocation` annotation and it doesn't delete it.

Is there a way to reset the map? I need to delete all the annotations from it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132173/how-to-remove-all-annotations-from-mkmapview-without-removing-the-blue-dot

Comment: but I want to delete just the annotation of the user location, not excluding it!

Answer (score 4):

You can just set the [showsUserLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsUserLocation) property of your mapView to NO.

```
 mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
```

Comment: Definitely NOT a solution. It removes my position on the map. How to remove ONLY the annotation on my position??? How to disable a click on the blue dot???

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can not edit `MKUserLocation` annotation. I mean you can not remove it from map annotation's array as it is a `read-only` property of `MKMapView`.

If you visit `MKMapView.h` class. You will find below line

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MKUserLocation *userLocation;
```

Here we can see that this property is a read only. So we can not delete it from `MKMapView` annotations array. How ever you face difficulties in calculation with other annotations then you can runtime hide it.

What I am trying to explain is when user location is not required any more you can set `NO` for user location property.

**For example with your code:**

```
NSMutableArray *annotationsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: mapView.annotations];
[mapView removeAnnotations: annotationsToRemove];

[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
NSLog(@"MapView annotations :%@", mapView.annotations);
```

Check `NSLog` output, you will see that `MKUserLocation` annotation is removed from `mapView.annotations` array.

It is the simple way I did follow. How ever I am not sure about there is other way to do this. Please leave a comment if you found any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the h insert

```
@property (weak)   MKAnnotationView *ulv;
```

In the m insert

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

        MKZoomScale currentZoomScale = mapView.bounds.size.width / mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width;
        NSLog(@"current zoom scale is %f",currentZoomScale);

        ulv = [mapView viewForAnnotation:mapView.userLocation];
                if( currentZoomScale > 0.049 ){
                    ulv.hidden = YES;
                }else{
                    ulv.hidden = NO;
                }

    }
```