# Best way to remove some annotations from an MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

To remove some annotations from an `MKMapView`, but not all of them, based on some condition, there seems to be 3 ways. I'd like to know which is the best one, and if there are any pitfalls with any of them. Thank you.

**First way**: removing annotations from annotations directly

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PinAnnotation class]]) {
        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}
```

As the docs say, the `mapView annotations` property is `readonly`. So I assume it's a copy that I can safely manipulate.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/annotations): `@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray <id<MKAnnotation>> *annotations`

**Second way**: adding the unwanted annotation to an array first

```
NSInteger toRemoveCount = myMap.annotations.count;
NSMutableArray *toRemove = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:toRemoveCount];
for (id annotation in myMap.annotations){
    if (annotation != myMap.userLocation){
        [toRemove addObject:annotation];
    }
}
[myMap removeAnnotations:toRemove];
```

This code is copied from the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2132236/873436)

It seems safer, but there's the overhead of creating the mutable array. If it's not necessary, I'd rather avoid it.

**Third way** : filtering the array

```
[_mapView.annotations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"!(self isKindOfClass: %@)", [MKUserLocation class]]];
```

(answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2915063/873436).

I didn't try out this one, but it seems rather elegant and powerful.

**What's the best way?**

Is it dangerous to remove annotations while itering through them?

Thank you for your knowledge and insights!

Comment: Knowing which one is "best" would require knowledge of how the map view internals are implemented.  I doubt that the performance differences between the ways are large enough to matter at all.  If I had to guess I'd say the second way is probably the most performant due to calling `removeAnnotations:` once instead of `removeAnnotation:` multiple times.

Comment: That's true that you would call `removeAnnotations:` only once, but you do have to build the array of annotations to remove...         Is the first way dangerous (removing an item of an array we're iterating through)?

Comment: It's technically possible that the map view internals could be implemented in a way for the first way to be dangerous but it currently isn't and I don't think it ever would be.

Comment: "As the docs say, the mapView annotations property is readonly. So I assume it's a copy that I can safely manipulate" -- that does not necessarily mean it's a copy. If it was copy, it would be explicitly stated as a copy. `(strong, nonatomic, copy)`